# How to invert int unsigned?

Tags: mysql

I am using the da datatype bigint unsigned in MySQL 5.7 and want to output the inverted value by query. So 30 becomes -30.

```
  SELECT
    mynumber * (- 1) as value
```

This returns the error:

```
Data truncation: BIGINT UNSIGNED value is out of range
```

How can that be done without changing the datatype?

Comment: I am talking about displaying not saving.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unsigned can only hold positive values. You need to cast to signed in order to get a negative value.

```
SELECT CAST(mynumber AS SIGNED) * -1 AS value
```

However, this will overflow if the value of `mynumber` is larger than the largest positive signed value (unsigned values can be twice as large as the corresponding signed types).

If this is just for display, you could simply concatenate the `-` character:

```
SELECT CONCAT('-', mynumber) AS value
```